# What options are there for an 11-hour layover in Bangkok?

Tags: air-travel, layovers, thailand, bangkok

On a flight from Frankfurt to Sydney (in a few weeks) via Bangkok, my layover in BKK (Suvarnabhumi) was changed from 90m to 11 hours... What is there for me to do, so time passes a bit more quickly? The boundary conditions are:

- I'm a German transit passenger without a visa for Thailand (at the moment)
- Scheduled arrival in BKK is 6:25 am, departure 17:50
- My physiological clock at arrival will be 1am.
- I can't sleep anywhere other than in a proper bed. Otherwise it's dozing a few moments, when I'm lucky.
- Willing to pay for lounge or other things.
- Legs are ok. I jog a marathon if you press me.
- I like Thai/Asian food in general.
- I'm a science/aerospace nerd.

E.g. Singapore Changi has this cactus garden which I enjoyed in the past. Recommendations appreciated!

Comment: check for a hotel inside the airport - they might be affordable and give a good rest.

Comment: @Aganju Good hint. It looks like the "Louis' Tavern Transit Hotel" is in the transit area and offers a special for "9am to 3pm".

Comment: Sorry but we don't give advice on what places to visit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

German passport holders are visa exempt for stays in Thailand up to 30 days.

You can catch a train from the airport to the city centre, with the trip taking ~20 minutes and cost 150 baht the last time I was there.

Given the above two facts, you could very easily head into central bangkok for the day - once you are out of the airport, the city is your oyster, enjoy some street food, grab a beer on a rooftop bar, visit a museum, take a water taxi etc. You can even go and find a cheap hotel somewhere outside the airport if you like, but assuming your final destination is in South East Asia, you are probably better off fighting through the need to sleep and enjoying your day of exploring.